# How do I check if my $wpdb->insert() was successful?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm trying to write a little script within my `footer.php` (which I'll later transform into a plugin) that send two form fields to a custom table (`wp_newsletter`). I'm already sending the form and writing to the table correctly, but I don't know how I can send a success or fail message back to the user. My current code is as follows:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="user_name">Name
  <input type="text" name="user_email">Email
  <input type="submit">
  <?php echo $message;  ?>
</form>

<?php
global $wpdb;
$table   = $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter";
$name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["user_name"] );
$email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["user_email"] );
$message = "";


if( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {
  if ( is_email($email) && isset($name)) {
    if ( $wpdb->insert( $table, array("name"  => $name, "email" => $email)) != false ) {
      $message = "Your subscription was sent.";
    }
  }
  else {
    if ( !is_email($email) ) {
        $message = "Invalid email address.";
    } elseif ( !isset($name) ) {
        $message = "The field name is mandatory.";
    } else {
        $message = "Both name and email fields are mandatory.";
    }
  }
} else {
    $message = "Please, try again later.";
}
?>


<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I (think) am testing it right, accordingly to the [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row) docs which says that:

> This function returns false if the row could not be inserted.
>   Otherwise, it returns the number of affected rows (which will always
>   be 1).

Comment: Where did you want the message to appear? You have your `echo $message` before the `$message` is created.

Comment: Hm, I was not sure if I could used it before declaration... But I wanted to show it under the form.

Comment: use this `!== FALSE` and try

Answer (score 5):

It returns either the number of rows inserted or false on error.

Maybe you can get id of inserted recode or false if the insert fails:

**refer link**: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/#return

So you can check like below:

```
$result_check = $wpdb->insert( $table, array("name"  => $name, "email" => $email));
if($result_check){
   //successfully inserted.
}else{
  //something gone wrong
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I realized that PHP is an acronym for "PHP Hypertext Preprocessor" -- emphasis on "preprocessor" -- I finally understood that I can't mix PHP and HTML and expect any kind of interactivity with the user. When a web page is served, the PHP creates the HTML and then the HTML is displayed by the browser. If the user does something the PHP must respond to, it **must** trigger a new PHP/HTML page to provide some sort of response. (An alternate would be to use AJAX to send data back and forth without loading a new page. Wordpress works well with AJAX and there are tutorials a google search away.)

For a simple form like yours, I would use javascript for error checking. If the form is not filled in, prevent form submission with JS. If the form is complete, the form's action can be a .php file that does the database insert and displays the success/failure message in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, scott. How could I create such `.php` file that would display the success/failure message to the user?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In a web environment, I would have the form's action be a .php file. The data is sent via GET to the target file. The data is then parsed and inserted into the DB. Then the .php file outputs HTML into a new web document that indicates success or failure. Note this does not give the user much opportunity to correct errors to achieve a better result once the new web page is loaded.

Comment: In Wordpress, however, I would consider trying AJAX. There are many good tutorials, and I would look in the Codex too, but here are two that worked for me: 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/ and 
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

AJAX allows DB access without loading a new web page. So you would have an element that has no HTML content until the AJAX returned with success/failure: 
`document.getElementById("results-div").innerHTML = content.result;`

Comment: The logic that handles the form is inside the same file of the form: the `footer.php`. I'm just trying to make it work this way, then I can separate it better when I'm done with the tests. Despite this, I don't want to send my form's data through a GET.

Comment: My mistake. You can use POST. It sounds like you want to do AJAX inside footer.php so it doesn't trigger a page reload. You will have to use javascript to send/receive the AJAX data, but you can create a new .php file to handle the AJAX call. (I put my .php files inside a plugin so all the dependencies are handled by the WP system.)

Comment: Thanks, scott. I'll read how I should post with AJAX inside WP. I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I came here via google and what helped me was using properties of $wpdb object:

```
$wpdb->last_error
```

shows the last error if present

```
$wpdb->last_query
```

shows the last query which gave the above error